# AutoMapper ignore a property in source and add value to destination property

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm posting this after trying so many posts related to this issue. But still I'm stuck with it.

I have 2 objects which I want to clone data from one to the other. But some properties are different in source as well as destination.

My source class is

```
public partial class ProductUnitMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PrimaryUnit { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SecondaryUnit { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 12)")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime Tstamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ForeignKey("EnterpriseId")]
    [InverseProperty("ProductUnitMasters")]
    public virtual Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
}
```

And my destination class is

```
public partial class ProductUnit
{
    public ProductUnit()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PrimaryUnit { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SecondaryUnit { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 12)")]
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime Tstamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    [InverseProperty("ProductUnits")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ProductUnit")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is, AutoMapper should ignore "EnterpriseId" property from the source and add a value to "CompanyId" property in destination, since other columns are identical.

I have created a MappingProfile as follows

```
CreateMap<ProductUnitMaster, ProductUnit>().ForSourceMember(x => x.EnterpriseId, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
```

But when I try to do the following in the controller I'm getting an error

```
var productUnit = _mapper.Map<ProductUnit>(productUnitMaster, opt =>
                    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.CompanyId = companyData.Id));
```

The error message says "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

[image]

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: *Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.* Please provide the complete exception message. Thanks.

Comment: @Yong Shun
I have edited and attached an image of the error message.

Comment: Sadly that the image didn't help too much, not much info can be analyzed from the image. If you are concerned about some sensitive data from the exception, I suggest you try to log the exception message first, modify it in the text file to remove those info and lastly paste into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue and I found what was my mistake here. As **Yong Shun** said, I couldn't find anything from the error message.

I missed to cast the destination object correctly. It should be as follows and resolved my issue.

```
var productUnit = _mapper. Map<IEnumerable<ProductUnit>>(productUnitMaster, opt =>
                    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.CompanyId = companyData.Id));
```